# Guestbook example for Google App Engine not starting up

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Not sure what happened. I had the first app in Google's App engine working then something changed. I finally jumped to a different PC re-installed everything, went through the tutorial and it still didn't work. Obviously I forgot a workaround for one of the many slips in this first app.

In the console it says

```
<terminated> Guestbook [Web Application] C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JDK1.0.6_35\bin\javaw.exe
```

then below that is the following:

```
Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=DIR             Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
 --generated_dir=DIR        Set the directory where generated files are created.
```

Comment: CAn you post the command you are running, and the path from which you are running it.

Comment: I am using Eclipse with the Google plugin. This is what I get in the console when I go to Run, Debug as, Web Application. And that is it. I tried loading using the JDK1.6.0_35 and JRE6.

Answer (score 0):

Delete .metadata folder from workspace. recreating and importing same project will solve problem.